# No Access to Admin Catalog Categories the link -- throws error page

Tags: magento-1.7, category, admin, adminhtml, catalog

After installing security patches SPUEE-1533 & SPUEE-5344 the category manager shows an error page instead of the category manager.
Anyone have any insight to this error? I'm stumped, and I don't understand what these errors mean.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:104:"Source model
"legenda/system_config_source_attribute_columns" not found for
attribute "sw_lg_cat_design"";i:1;s:4073:"

`#0 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387):`
Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "l...')

`#1 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201):`
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()

`#2 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113):`
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array,
Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))

`#3 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144):`
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()

`#4 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862):`
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()

`#5 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140):`
Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

`#6 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238):`
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()

`#7 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456):`
Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))

`#8 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55):`
Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')

`#9 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238):`
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()

` #10 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456):`
Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))

`#11 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82):`
Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')

`#12 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238):`
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()

`#13 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456):`
Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))

`#14 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472):`
Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...',
'category.edit')

`#15 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239):`
Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...',
'category.edit')

`#16 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205):` Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)
Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))

`#17 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210):`
Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))

`#18 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344):`
Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()

`#19 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269):`
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()

`#20 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275):`
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)

`#21 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201):`
Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()

`#22 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419):`
Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()

`#23 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):`
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')

`#24 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):` 
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

`#25 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):`
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

`#26 /home/MY_Site/public_html/app/Mage.php(683):` Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

`#27 /home/MY_Site/public_html/index.php(87):`
Mage::run('', 'store')

`#28 {main}";s:3:"url";s:34:"/index.php/admin/catalog_category/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have probably uninstalled an extension named something like legenda, which has left category attributes behind that rely on it.

Magento doesn't have admin UI for category attributes, so these need to be cleaned up manually. This is a process that you'll want to try out on your development site first - if you don't have a development site you have bigger problems.

The simplest approach is probably to look at the [prefix_]eav_attribute table in your Magento DB, and look for the row with the attribute code sw_lg_cat_design - this will probably have legenda/system_config_source_attribute_columns in the source_model field. Blanking the source_model field will probably let your page load, or deleting this attribute completely might be an option - but until you understand what this did, you're at a high risk of breaking something else.

The other option would be to ask for support from the provider of your legenda theme, and ask them for a clean uninstaller.

Comment: okay i did delete three attributes
sw_lg_cat_banner
sw_lg_cat_design
sw_lg_cat_position

this did not let me regain the category manager.
im guessing the admin before me was doing something with legenda.
so....
The error page still shows when trying to view the category manager
is there something in the security patches that would cause issues with the category manager layout?

Comment: here is the error now
a:5:{i:0;s:104:"Source model "megamenu/category_attribute_source_type_style" not found for attribute "sw_cat_block_type"";i:1;s:4073:"#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "m...')
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()

etc.....etc....etc......

Comment: It sounds like a bunch of modules that your site was using got disabled. You might be better off re-enabling those modules than deleting anything that references them. In this case, it looks like a `megamenu` module has disappeared (or at least some of its models have).

Comment: so .... if i start blowing away eav attributes are there other tables in the database that refer to those attribute id's ..table entries that i should be aware of so that i know to remove the references to those eav attributes as well.??  if so anything obvious that maybe i just dont know about.

Comment: also, i think you are right about the megamenu its not part of the admin area at all and i dont see it in the extensions but i did come accross an attribute group name of """ Legenda Design"""" in the eav_attribute_group  table. I dont want to jack up the site as it is. How can i tell if removing the sw_XXX_XXX attribute entities etc  will screw up the site or not befor actually removing the info from the db???

Comment: Update: so after some investigation there are  smartwave_blog tables.
I does look as though these tables are leftovers from a partially unistalled extension. There are no entries related to this item in the core_data_config table nor is there any sign of this item within the list of installed extensions...........stay tuned for the results of the clean up.

Comment: Basically attributes can reference code on disk for their sources. If that code is gone as happens when an extension is removed, the attribute is broken and needs to be removed or modified too.

Comment: thats exactly true xyphoid......i removed the tables from the database and the admin catalog manager displays and functions as its supposed to.

Comment: I had the same problem. Installed a new theme to quickly have a look at it, but the DB backup that I created before the installation had been corrupted. So after disabling the theme and removing the files I had to delete all the `smartwave` tables in the DB and remove all attributes with an attribute code starting with `sw_` from `eav_attribute`. Now it's working again.